# How to type within today From 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to add "within today" (i.e. From 00:00:00 to 23:59:59) in Laravel ?

```
$grpcnt = DB::table('groups') 
                      ->where('owner_id', $u_id)
                      ->whereBetween('created_at', xxx,xxx)
                      ->count();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to get count of today group then you may use like this.

```
DB::table('groups')->where('owner_id', $u_id)
                  ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
                  ->count();
```

Or as per your requirement

```
$start = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();  //2019-07-27 00:00:00.000000
$end = Carbon::now()->endOfDay(); //2019-07-27 23:59:59.000000


DB::table('groups')->where('owner_id', $u_id)
                   ->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use carbon for this, with start of the day and end of the day

```
$grpcnt = DB::table('groups') 
            ->where('owner_id', $u_id)
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [ Carbon::now()->startOfDay(),Carbon::now()->endOfDay()])
            ->count();
```